# Canon Mx772 printer recognized, drivers loaded...but all print jobs "Held"

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

BRAND NEW to Ubuntu but loving it so far. I have a Canon MX772 wireless printing running on  my network and am able to print fine from a PC and Mac.

Using the printers IP, Ubuntu was able to find it and I accepted all of the "recommended" items (it found a Canon MX770 driver). Everything seems to load fine...but the test page does not print, nor does any print commands make it to the printer.

If I open the print dialogue jobs are shown as "held" and when I look at the jobs attributes, I see `Job printer state message=cannot specify model number` and then a few lines down `job state reasons=aborted by system`. If I try to `resume` it immediately goes back to `held`.

I can successfully ping the IP of the printer. Would be very appreciative of other ideas...printing is the last check in the box before I am all set up. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the way to solve it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the system-config-printer utility in Linux Mint 17. Click the "+ Add" button. Next, choose "Network Printer". It should display your Canon printer twice, once by cnijet format (e.g. cnijnet:/88-87-17-89-c1-62), and once as "LPD network printer via DNS-SD". Choosing the LPD daemon cleared up this error for me.